# How to move project to another users project area in TFVC

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Our TFS is not set up to be used in the traditional way since we moved it from Visual Source Safe which had a user\project hierarchy. Now I need to do a Move command to give another user a project that he is taking over from me and I want to use Move so it will preserve history. I understand that the parent of what you are moving must have mapping set up in order to get the option to Move activated and I've done that but it gives an error when attempting the move.

I hope the picture gives a better understanding. Help! Please!

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the errors when you move?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the 'Move' option will only move source files without their history information. TFS doesn't provide any feature to move items with history. You could use some other tools like [TFS Integration tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Willy-PSchaub.TeamFoundationServerIntegrationToolsMarch2012Relea).

Actually, when you use the 'Move' option to move, TFS first copy your files to your target place then delete the original files, so it looks like a migration.
That's why the history can't be seen after moving. The old history is still under the original place.

In addition, when you 'Move', the parent folder should be mapped and the target place folder should also be mapped.